# How to submit this form using jQuery AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP email form and the user enters their email and it sends them the link to the file they uploaded. How would I submit that form with AJAX?

Right now, I have it where they click on a link to go to the page with the email form on it, and I am passing the `$target_path` variable in the URL so the link to the uploaded file can be in the email. Here's the PHP I have on the "Successfully uploaded" page to go to `email.php`:

```
<?php echo "<a href='email.php?target_path=".$target_path."'>Click here</a> to get the link sent to your email." ?>
```

Here's the source of `email.php`:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload File</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
font-family:arial,sans-serif;
}
.error {
color:red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
function spamcheck($field)
  {
  //filter_var() sanitizes the e-mail
  //address using FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL
  $field=filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

  //filter_var() validates the e-mail
  //address using FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL
  if(filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
    return TRUE;
    }
  else
    {
    return FALSE;
    }
  }

if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
  {//if "email" is filled out, proceed

  //check if the email address is invalid
  $mailcheck = spamcheck($_REQUEST['email']);
  if ($mailcheck==FALSE)
    {
    echo "Invalid email, please try again.";
    }
  else
    {//send email
    $to = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
    $subject = "Your file has been uploaded to our site and here's a link to it" ;
    $message = "
Hello,

Your file has been uploaded to our site. Here is a link to it for future reference, keep this email if you want to remember the link to your file: http://www.example.com/upload/".$_REQUEST['target_path']."

Thank you.";

    mail($to,$subject,$message, "From: noreply@example.com" );
    echo "Email has been sent. Please check your inbox and/or spam folder.";
    }
  }
else
  {//if "email" is not filled out, display the form
  echo "<form method='post' action=''>
  Email: <input name='email' type='text' /><br /><br />
  <input type='submit' />
  </form>";
  }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, when they click the link to go to `email.php` on the "Successfully Uploaded File" page (`upload.php`) it passes the `$target_path` variable so it will be able to send a link to the uploaded file.

I would like to put the email form right on `upload.php` (the page where the file upload form gets submitted to) and then submit that email form with jQuery AJAX. I just don't know how to make that work. I'll also need that variable to still be passed, but I don't think it would be in the URL, it would probably be in somewhere else in the AJAX code.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Nathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is the JS bit of code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#emailbtn').click(function(){
            //This is short form of php echo
        var target_path = <?php=$target_path?> 

            //Get eMail from input
            var email = $('#email').val(); 

            //Send form to email.php using GET method
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: "email.php",
            data: ({"target_path" :  target_path, "email" : email}),
            success: function(message)
            {   
                $("#btnspan").empty().append(message);
            }
        });         
    });
});
```

This is HTML bit of code

```
<span id="btnspan">Your eMail: <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /> <button id="emailbtn" class="button">eMail me the link</button></span>
```

Seems your email.php return valid messages, so what will happen when you click on the button is that content provided by your php will replace the form content! Page does NOT refresh.

One thing I would suggest you change is the GET method, change it to POST! For php I assume you know it's `$_POST[varname]` to retrieve the value and for the JS, just change AJAX type to POST.

Comment: Thanks. But `$target_path` is supposed to be the URL to the file, not the email. `$target_path` is a variable I made in the PHP. I'll try using this code but I'll have to fix some stuff since `target_path` was supposed to be the file name so the link to the file could be sent and not the email. Thanks for the answer, this code looks good. :)

Comment: You can pass that to the email.php as well, just pass one more variable, check my post again, I have edited the ans.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will be using this. But my webhost, 000webhost, deleted my account and I lost all of my PHP so I have to redo it unfortunately :( I had edited the PHP online and the files on my computer were out of date.

Comment: ouch...I use 000webhost, the free service, never had problem with them but anyways, I feel your pain.

Comment: Yeah, they deleted my account because they don't allow PHP file uploading unless I upgrade. Really made me mad. I am recreating my account for another purpose but now... they are taking forever to verify it. I have email.php (because I was in the middle of editing it when they canceled my account so I hurried and copied the code and pasted it into notepad) but I didn't get uploaded.php and I contacted them and they said since I did something against the TOS it can't be restored. (I had no clue it was against the TOS)

Answer (score 2):

You could add a hidden input to the form containing the target_path value, so you avoid passing it through the url, and you can easily access it from the jQuery AJAX callback.

```
<input type='hidden' id='path' value='<?php echo $target_path;?>'/>
```

and add

```
var path=$('#path').val();
var email=$('#email').val();
```

and send both of them with the data parameter.

```
data:{'path' : path, 'email' : email}
```

Otherwise first post almost covered it.

Comment: Thanks! :) Using the hidden field is much better. I'm trying that right now. This hidden field will also make it where the user wont be able to edit anything on it since it wont be visible.

Comment: Why do extra work, just echo your path right within declaration in JS bit, no need for hidden input elements.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend the **JQuery Form** plugin found at http://jquery.malsup.com/form/.
It makes it trivial to add ajax functionality to new or existing forms and I use it on applications that could be run in both ajax mode and non ajax mode.

Comment: Thanks but using the jQuery Form plugin will be a little hard to implement to my file upload and stuff because I already have all of this code, ya know?

Comment: Well, the upload and post can be handled almost exactly as before. Only minimal changes is needed and you could return some json encoded data from the ajax post target page once upload is done. Either to trigger a function or to display directly.